# How to convert JSON to AppleScript properties

Tags: applescript, json

How can I get AppleScript to run this query and save each value (country, city, etc.) as an AppleScript variable?

```
http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8?fields=country,city,isp,org,as,mobile,proxy,message
```

I'm trying to get [information about IP and domain](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:returned_values#selectable_output) and set the value of some variables.

I was not sure how to even run the query from AppleScript so I used `do shell script` to call `curl`:

```
set IPAddress to "8.8.8.8"
set link to "http://ip-api.com/json/" & IPAddress & "?fields=country,city,isp,org,as,mobile,proxy,message"
set curl_command to "curl " & link

do shell script curl_command
```

The result is JSON formatted text. Is AppleScript's text delimiter the only option for parsing the result?

Comment: As a tip, use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to turn off syntax highlighting where it's not wanted, such as that URL above.

Comment: If the below answered your question please accept the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSON_Examples.html) app available on the AppStore. Then you simply do something like this:

```
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set json to fetch JSON from "http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8?fields=country,city,isp,org,as,mobile,proxy,message"
    set countryName to |country| of json
end tell
```

Result: `"United States"`

Comment: Nice utility for free! In the past I've used [**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in `bash` script, but will use this the next time I need to parse JSON. from AppleScript. +1