# Unable to convert certain keywords in record to JSON

Tags: json

I am using [JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSON_Examples.html) to convert record to JSON. I have run into difficulty that using certain words inside the record produces empty JSON. As you can see from the screenshot, first two variables (`test1` and `test2`) silently fail and produce empty JSON. Here's source to the script in question - [link](https://pastebin.com/GEBzSX1A). My question is simple - why `test1` and `test2` produce empty JSON?

Ps. I am using these names as a part of 3rd party API which I have no control of (including naming conventions for variables) - [link](https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/projects.md#create-project).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` and `id` are both keywords within the [AppleScript language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).

It may be possible to quote these words to avoid their being interpreted as special cases. Try using the [pipe character](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309389/how-to-convert-json-to-applescript-properties) or [double angle brackets/chevrons](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_raw_data.html) to wrap these keys.